# why the vscode runcode error appear in windows

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

for some python file, when I run code in vscode,the terminal will display [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NgohV.png),not [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9AXb2.png). I donnot know why the **"/usr/bin/env"** will appear,I just know that is for Unix.
sorry for my poor English.

I just want to know the reason why it appear.

Comment: why don't you use a launch config and not CodeRunner

Answer (score 0):

"/usr/bin/env" is appearing when you directly execute python file with vs code extentions . you can either use that or simply open terminal in program location and execute command - python programname.py  / python3 programname.py